# Can anybody connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I keep trying apt-get update, but it gives me 504 errors for [mirrordirector.raspbian.org](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org)

I have tried

```
wget mirrordirector.raspbian.org
```

and it gives me the following output:
[image: wget output from rPi]

If anybody can connect without a problem then I'll know its not a server issue, and I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Are you connecting directly or through a proxy server?  I just connected without any issue ... a gateway timeout usually means that you connected to some intermediate proxy server or CDN (like Akamai) and the destination website didn't respond

Comment: everything works like a charm, check you internet connection and/or router settings.

Comment: OK, I was guessing it was my ISP and this reaffirms my suspicions. I'll have to connect to the internet at a friends house and try it there; I'll keep you updated.

Comment: The question is old but I had same problem today of being able to ping but not to get data with wget also from google.com so here my solution: after a lot of trials just to give it a try I've launched rpi-update and it worked, then after a reboot also apt-get started working. Seems crazy but so that was

Comment: @andrea given that it was a 504 error (search Google for HTTP error codes) implies that the problem was with the server not the client (Pi). The update and reboot probably took enough time for the server issue to be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

504 gateway timeout means a proxy server failed to connect to the server behind it.

mirrordirector.raspbian.org is served directly by an apache instance with the mirrorbrain module. There is no reverse proxying or similar on the server end currently so it is unlikely that the error came from our server.

Some problem with a forced proxy in your ISPs network seems like the most likely explanation.